# Volume of hyperboloid limited by two planes (multivariable calculus).

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

As usual the teachers solution sheet takes leaps and bounds over steps in the solution that I need to understand it.

Q:

Determine the volume of the body limited by $x^2+y^2-3z^2=1$, $z=1$ and $z=-1$.

So that's a hyperboloid, something like this (but also limited by $z=1$ and $z=-1$).

[image: Hyperboloid]

The teacher jumps over the part where I always struggle, where you determine the limits of integration based on the given curves. I never get it right.

So, the first step of the solution here:

$$V=\int_{-1}^1\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le1+3z^2}dxdydz=...$$

I get what is happening, but **what's the reasoning** behind rewriting the limit to $x^2+y^2\le1+3z^2$? **As I interpret it you get a circle with a radius from $0$ to $1+3z^2$. Am I mistaken?**

In the next step the teacher jumps straight into this:

$$...=\int_{-1}^1\pi(1+3z^2)dz=...$$

**What happened there**? Usually in these cases I have to turn to polar coordinates, because they are easier to understand.

It ends straight up with

$$...=\pi[z+z^3]_{-1}^1=4\pi$$

Except my questions above, I would really like to get some guidance in how to think when it comes to the limits of integration in cases like these. **What am I aiming to achieve?**

Thank you for your time, it's invaluable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural to slice the region by planes parallel to the $xy$-plane going from $z=-1$ to $z=1$. The intersection of each such plane with the region is a disk (filled in circle) of radius $\sqrt{1+3z^2}$. So the volume of the region is given by the single integral
$$\int_{-1}^1 A(z)\,dz\,,$$
where $A(z)$ is the cross-sectional area of the slice at height $z$. This is, in turn, $\pi(1+3z^2)$, since the area of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$.

It's really a mess to write the integral $A(z)$ as a double integral in Cartesian coordinates, so your teacher skipped that and just wrote the region as $x^2+y^2\le 1+3z^2$.

Your instinct to use cylindrical coordinates isn't bad. Because of the shape of the region, we want $dz$ on the outside and then we can represent $A(z)$ as a double integral in polar coordinates:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{1+3z^2}} r \,dr\,d\theta}_{A(z)}\ dz$$

Comment: That is an excellent explanation, got it! Do you have any general advice on what to look or aim for when trying to figure out the limits of integration?

Comment: I generally tell students to do most cylindrical coordinates problems in the order $dz\,dr\,d\theta$ and most spherical coordinates problems in the order $d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$ (assuming standard American math notation). As with cartesian coordinates, you should start from the outside and work your way in, asking yourself what the limiting values of your particular variable are for fixed values of the variables on the outside.

Comment: That's great help. I will ponder on all this wisdom. And yeah, we use the same math notation here in Sweden, most of our studies are conducted in English and with English literature. Thank you again!